# How to load a python IDE shell environment and run a python script with one single shell command?

Tags: python, bash, ide, alias, environment

I want to be able to run my python script with one simple alias in terminal.

Currently I can run my script by loading up my IDE environment

```
/packages/.../bin/startapp python -e PythonTractorTools
```

and then once in this environment I run it with

```
execfile('myfile.py')
```

How can I do all of this with one shell command? I've tried and failed with 2 part .Cshrc alias like this:

```
alias runscript 'load environment; run script'
```

And I've tried and failed with a separate python script like this:

```
import os
import myfile
import time

os.system("/packages/.../bin/startapp python -e PythonTractorTools")
time.sleep(5)
os.system('myfile.py')
```

Comment: IDEs and command-line don't always mix well. Do you have to open the IDE to run your script? See if it is possible to just re-create the IDE environment without actually loading the IDE.

Comment: I can create the environment in Pycharm, but this is also something I was trying to avoid. Basically I just want to be able to run the script as quickly as possible, with the option maybe even to run it as a cron tab.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it like this. I am assuming you are on a Linux environment and you have bash available. csh will not be much different.

First I will create my python script, like below. Please note the use of first line in the script. Make sure that your python3 is available there. Otherwise change it as per your situation. Save the file as MyFirstPythonAlias.py

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6
import numpy as np 
print(np.zeros(shape=(3,4)))
```

This program will print whenever you call MyFirstPythonAlias.py from the bash shell.
Now I will open my .bashrc in an editor and in the bottom, I will add the alias. Suppose I wish to name my alias as TempDelete, then I will type the line in the .bashrc as below

```sh
alias TempDelete="FullPathTo/MyFirstPythonAlias.py"
```

then I will restart my shell or open a new one and if you just type TempDelete, it should do what you want. In this case it will print out a 3 x 4 matrix filled with zeros.
Please let me know if this is what you wanted. Otherwise, I might have not read your requirement correctly.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't solve the issue of loading the environment required to run the script.

Comment: Yeah. I see that now. IDE are mostly GUI based so based on some sort of  GUI enviroment (e.g. X11) will be needed for them. Command line however does not need this. I think by design they are different. csh/bash are command line shells and I am not sure how will you load the entire environment there. If, all you want is load all the packages (inside your environment) that are there then there can be a workaround (lengthy or small) but loading the full environment .. I am not sure .. Best wishes.